# Angular material input labels always floating for any input type

Tags: html, css, angularjs, input, angular-material

I need to display a fixed (no animation) floating label on every md-input-container containing either md-input, md-select, md-datepicker or md-autocomplete. I actually managed to have it work on md-input by adding class="md-input-has-placeholder" on md-input-container, but it's not working on any other kinds of input.

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder">
    <label style="font-size:15px;">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name">
</md-input-container>
```

[result expected example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXyZR.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

you can just add placeholder="" to your field.. i've tested with input and textarea, don't know if it works with all components.. hope it helps

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Text (always floating)</label>
        <textarea ng-model="ngModel" rows="1" md-maxlength="150" placeholder=""></textarea>
    </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to override some CSS styles from `angular-material`.
This should get you close to what you are trying to achieve.

```
md-input-container label {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,6px,0) scale(.75) !important;
   transform: translate3d(0,6px,0) scale(.75) !important;
   -webkit-transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
   transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
   transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
   transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
   top: auto !important;
}

md-input-container .md-select-placeholder > span:not(.md-select-icon) {
  color: transparent;
}
```

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/BQMNyy

Comment: Almost perfect, thanks. I've added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53833233/4135063) with a minor improvement that was necessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class="active" to label.

```
<md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder">
    <label style="font-size:15px;" class="active">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: it's not working on md-datepicker, md-autocomplete and md-select

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the labels colored, you can always add `md-input-focused` class to the md-input-container.

Answer (score 0):

For [@angular/material](https://github.com/angular/material2) you can set property **floatPlaceholder="always"** on <md-input-container> tag.
This Works fine since 2.0.0-beta.2. I know that it's not related to your question, but many people will search for this problem and find your question (as I did).

```
<md-input-container floatPlaceholder="always">
   <input mdInput type="text" id="username" formControlName="Username"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement over @kuhnroyal's answer (upvote it!), accounting for `ng-required` possibly present in the inputs, and providing a class so that you can apply this style only when you want it:

Add the following CSS to your page:

```
md-input-container.floating-label-always label {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,6px,0) scale(.75) !important;
  transform: translate3d(0,6px,0) scale(.75) !important;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
  transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),width .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1),-webkit-transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top: auto !important;
}
md-input-container.floating-label-always .md-select-placeholder > span:not(.md-select-icon) {
  color: transparent;
}
md-input-container.floating-label-always .md-select-placeholder > span:not(.md-select-icon):after {
  content: none !important;
}
```

To apply it, add the `floating-label-always` class to your `md-input-container`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this directive out https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInputContainer#attributes
md-no-float. Make sure you are using **placeholder** in the input instead of an actual  element